# Cognos 11 Reports: I am using a date prompt in a filter and in data items but receive Error QE-DEF-0426

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

I have a date prompt in a filter:
`[Fiscal Year - INFY] = substring(year(?Date?),3,2)` 
but also use the prompt in a data item to determine how to calculate inventory amount:
`CASE CAST(month(?Date?),INTEGER)

WHEN 1 THEN 0
WHEN 2 THEN [Jan]...etc`

This code worked when I did not use a prompt but used current_date instead.  Any help would be much appreciated!

I received the following error code:

QE-DEF--0459 CCLException
QE-DEF-0426 the function 'month' is not available in Function Set Id '_None'.  Specify a Function Set Id on the appropriate data source in the model.

Comment: Did you put in the prompts in both places at once or in one place (and possibly it worked then) and then in the second place?  You would probably want to try to identify where the error is coming from, which would usually be done by controlling for the variables.  In this case, remove the prompt from one place and see what happens and if it works do the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions are missing the _ in front of them.

_month ( date_expression )
Returns the value of the month field in "date_expression".

_year ( date_expression )
Returns the value of the year field in "date_expression".

If you use the functions as they are in the function list you'll be better off when it comes to query processing and query decomposition.